# HTTP OPTIONS method blocked on osx (10.9.2)

Tags: macos, http, http-options-method

I have issue with my mac. I can't send a http options request from my browser or using curl cmd. I don't have a clue why. It's not working for all users on my comp. I turned off the firewall and all unnecessary services but problem is still here.

I've recorded videos showing the problem:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hacq8rYXNNk
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yapatgPnudQ

Comment: What happens when you run that command against a server that actually supports the OPTIONS method? e.g. http://www.webdav.org

Comment: the same => empty response. When I start same server on localhost, it works.

Comment: Strange, I do get some output, same OS and everything. I suggest breaking out Wireshark and investigating what actually travels over the wire.

Comment: Just tested with Wireshark log.. It seems there are actualy no requests made when using OPTIONS method. GET/POST etc are logged correctly but I don't have any OPTIONS request in Wireshark log.

Comment: Try adding -v to the curl command? That's it for me though, good luck :/

Comment: I'm testing clean install on mac mini... It work just right on clean so step by step I'm running my configuration. Hope I find out what causes the issue. Thank you a lot for your time!!

Comment: Recently I had similar problem when using hotel's WiFi, but on 3G it worked fine.

Comment: For me it's same when using 3G.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be related to Cisco AnyConnect. Fixed it for my colleague by reinstalling Cisco AnyConnect with limited security.

See: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2559-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client-may-block-cors-ajax-options-requests.htm

Comment: Ok! this is possible.

Comment: I lost 2 hours of my life to this.  Thanks.

Comment: I have been bashing my head against this for the past week. Thank you so much for this.